# How to enable intellisense for jquery in zend studio?

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, zend-studio

I'm currently working on an application based on zend framework. I've done some applications that uses dojo, and zend studio intellisense seems to be supporting it quite well. But when I moved to an application that uses jquery there was something missing and it seemed to be from the part of zend studio intellisense. So how can I add/improve the intellisense support for jquery on zend studio?

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable jQuery on Zend Studio welcome page, and then enable it for specific project (using project context menu Configure->Enable jQuery support).

Afterwards you should see content-assist for jQuery types and methods when editing HTML and JS files.